# Ruby POST request with JSON body

Tags: ruby, json, post

I am trying to write a POST request in Ruby to an API I published via the Microsoft Machine Learning studio. I am returning error 400 with the following:

```
require 'unirest'
require 'json'

uri = "https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/a0e65d42d21c423fa4027d98f6ad364f/services/0d797f1b26d4410cae35c50d25d1c7cd/execute?api-version=2.0&details=true"
apikey = "some api key"
params = {some json body}
response = Unirest.post(uri, headers: {"content_length" =>"235", "content-type" => "application/json", "authorization" => "Bearer" + " " + apikey}, parameters: params)
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to structure this request. According to the documentation:

Authorization:Bearer abc123

Required. Pass the API Key here. Obtain this key from the publisher of the API.

Content-Length

Required. The length of the content body.

Content-Type:application/json

Required if the request body is sent in JSON format.

Accept: application/json

Optional. Use the header to receive the response in JSON format.

I'm not great with Ruby but my text editor doesn't seem to like it when i use : between the header and value instead of =>.

The body I need to include in the request if shown like this in the documentation:

```
{
  "Inputs": {"input1": {
      "ColumnNames": [
        "Case Number",
        "Case Type",
        "Address",
        "Description",
        "Case Group",
        "Date Case Created",
        "Last Inspection Date",
        "Last Inspection Result",
        "Status",
        "Permit and Complaint Status URL",
        "Latitude",
        "Longitude",
        "Location"
      ],
      "Values": [
        [
          "0",
          "value",
          "value",
          "value",
          "value",
          "",
          "",
          "value",
          "value",
          "value",
          "0",
          "0",
          "value"
        ],
        [
          "0",
          "value",
          "value",
          "value",
          "value",
          "",
          "",
          "value",
          "value",
          "value",
          "0",
          "0",
          "value"
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "GlobalParameters": {}}
```

Everytime I throw that in the editor and try to run the script I get all kinds of errors. Unexpected , expecting end, etc...

Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Unirest explicitely usess : between header names and content, be careful when using third party libraries as you need to read their docs carefully: Here is the link for unirest's RUBY http://unirest.io/ruby.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED IT!

```
response = Unirest.post uri, headers:{"content-length" => "500", "content-type" => "application/json", "authorization" => "Bearer" + " " + apikey}, parameters: {"Inputs" => {"input1" => {"ColumnNames" => ["Case Number", "Case Type", "Address", "Description", "Case Group", "Date Case Created", "Last Inspection Date", "Last Inspection Result", "Status", "Permit and Complaint Status URL", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Location"], "Values" => [["0", "value","value","value","value","", "","value","value","value","0", "0", "value"],["0", "value","value","value","value","", "","value","value","value","0", "0", "value"]]}}, "GlobalParameters" => {}}.to_json
```

TL;DR

Had to nest an array within an array nested within a couple hashes.

Answer (score 0):

try `.to_json` after your hash. I.e. `{"content_length" =>"235"}.to_json` and params.to_json

Comment: So I gave that a shot-Still getting errors in the editor saying the syntax is incorrect with to_json.